# Can I get the transient value in the processing of "CSS3 transient animation"

Tags: javascript, css, transform, transient

for example ,when I'm using transient to implement a 2s duration animation by change the value of translate(x, y).  How can I get the current value of translate(x, y) at the 0.5s moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can. By setting the transition timing function to `linear`, you could easily estimate it, or by using the bezier curves for the other timing functions you could work it out.

I'd suggest that if you need to find this then you might be better off using either animations (you can define where something is using keyframes), or animating using javascript (either on DOM elements, canvas or SVG).